# Looking for a specific fitting

Tags: beer, equipment

I bought a blichmann therminator, and I want to hook up stainless camlock/ groove 1/2" nipples to all 4 "openings".  Problem is, the coolant line in/ out are 3/4" GHT, which, while I understand why they did that, really makes standardizing on a quickconnect system a true pain in the butt.

I have been looking for a 3/4 GHT female to either 1/2" camlock/groove or 1/2" NPT male in stainless, and have come up completely empty handed.  Has anyone seen these/ know where I can order some?

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you need stainless for the hose connections? Brass is fine for water. Here's a brass 3/4" female GHT x male 1/2" NPT. http://morebeer.com/view_product/17391//Brass_Hose_-_Female_Garden_Hose_Thread_x_1_2_in%22_MPT

Comment: well... technically I don't NEED stainless for any of it... but everything else is stainless and would bother me every time I looked at it.  :)

Comment: bargainfittings.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several female GHT x 1/2" MPT fittings on ebay in brass as well as the link I posted in the comment. I've never seen any in stainless - of course that doesn't mean they don't exist - but I'd imagine it's a very niche product, and hence expensive. Given that brass garden hose fittings are usually acceptable, GHT stainless fittings not a high-volume product.

An alternative is to use a stainless GHT x barb bitting and a short length of 1/2" hose with a camlock on the end. On one end of the hose is female GHT x 1/2" barb, and on the other, a stainless 1/2" barb x 1/2" MPT and then the camlock (or use the barbed camlock fitting to avoid a big lump of hardware on the end.) [fittingsandadapters.com](http://fittingsandadapters.com/garhosbarsta.html) lists a stainless Female GHT x 1/2" barb for $35.70.

If you hadn't already got the Therminator, I would have recommended going for the chillers at [Dudadiesel](http://www.dudadiesel.com/search.php?query=b3-23a) - you can get them with 1/2" MPT threads on all 4 ports, avoiding the GHT problem entirely, but I imagine you don't want to hear that now!

Comment: I ended up going with brass.